# How to check wether am in correct page after submitting the form using assertion selenium/TestNG/Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion, verify

This is my scenario "i am submitting the form and once I submit its navigate into page call WebTable.I want to confirm now am incorrect page after submitting the form"

how to check this by using assertion? please help   selenium /Java /TestNG

Comment: You can validate with any of the dynamic page elements loaded after login.For example,there will be a user name or log out text/icon after log in is successful so you can validate with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you click the form you wait for an element to show up using Webdriverwait.
You pull the current URL and check with value and assert it.

```
submitBtn.click();
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("etc")));
expectedUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
Assert.assertTrue(expectedUrl.equals("something"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you have basically two options available to you.

1. Wait for the URL to contain what you expect using `driver.getCurrentUrl()`
2. Wait for a specific element that will only appear on the next page

If you don't have a class already built for performing retries, you can use [FluentWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium provides a good practice for this type of validation, and here comes FluentWait:

```
 FluentWait fluentWait = new FluentWait(webDriverBPO).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20)).pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).ignoring(NullPointerException.class);
```

All you have to do after your last action, is to wait until URL contains your expected value:

```
fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("your URL or keyword from URL"));
```

You can try also to wait for any element from the new page, but the URL loads faster than the content, so you will save some time (as you don't need to perform any other validations).